# Network Error on some Mobile Safari Request in production

Tags: ios, reactjs, safari, network-error-logging

I have a ReactJS Application in Production. It uses Axios and GraphQl to make requests to our Backend.

On some Safari sessions and not in all Requests, we get a Low Level Network Error. It comes directly from Axios.

Axios catch it, return “null” as a response and the page goes kaboom.

Before I ask the question, let me elaborate on some things:

- All Requests are https. All Certificates are up to date and working.
- Both Backend and Frontend are on the same Domain so no Cors. No Options Request in Production.
- There aren’t any Non ASCII Characters in the Payload.
- Please. Don’t tell me to upgrade to next iOS versions. It’s in production. Not my device.

Finally. The request’s doesn’t seems to reach the Load Balanacer which makes me think it is cancelled. But why? We see sessions in Sentry where 10 Requests work and then on a subsequent one “Network Error”.

I kind of replicated by blocking all cookies on iPhone. But I have no idea how to fix it. Can you help me? I don’t see anything code wise that makes it this. On Chrome, Firefox and Desktop Safari in works.

It happens only on iPhone and iPad and versions between 11 and 16..

P.S: The code is very standard. A simple Axios Client POST Request using GrapgQL with 2 very simple interceptors just for logging Errors in Sentry.

I tried proper cancellation but hitch didn’t work in case there was an intermittent state on navigation change. Didn’t work.

Looked into the Ngnix side of things. Pretty standard stuff there that worked on both Browser and Curl.

Comment: What output you have in your postman, and what is error exactly? I'm asking this questions because I believe 90% the mistake is in your back end, but I have to be sure.

Comment: Postman is working fine. Backend is also pretty Vanilla Node with Fastify. Re. The Error is literally the following: “Error: Network Error”.

Comment: Re. the backend I also thought of enabling cors and putting allowedHeaders all the headers we have. We have 2 custom ones. But we are in the same domain. Why would we need it?

Comment: "Error: Network Error" general means cannot find the server (url). Can you check the proxy you use? Have you checked your proxy version, in which Safari software is supported and how you need to use it (this is my last idea)?

Comment: Also, are you using eg Cloudflare?

Comment: Nope. Long running server on K8s. In AWS with ELB and Ngnix in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have figured it out. I've adjusted my nginx config file to use http/2 and that *seems* to have fixed it.

I think maybe there is some bug with http/1.1 in Safari.

Edit: I have disabled http/2 enhanced prioritization in Cloudflare too, which was responsible for some issues (https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/troubleshooting/performance/http2-and-enhanced-http2-prioritization-options-may-affect-content-loading-on-iossafari-devices/)